# PHP - number_format float number

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting

how can i format a float number, exemple 6099.99, to: **6,099.99 or 6.099,99**

i've tried the function `number_format()` and `money_format()` like this:

`number_format(6099.99,2,'.',',')` // output **6,00**

`setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');`
`echo money_format('%.2n', $number)` // output **6,00**

Thx in advanced

Comment: I tried `echo number_format(6099.99,2,'.',',');` its give `6,099.99`? What's your problem?

Comment: ___money_format___ **Warning** This function has been _DEPRECATED_ as of PHP 7.4.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have the parameters the wrong way round.
Param 3 is the decimal seperator and param 4 is the Thousands seperator

```
echo number_format(6099.99,2,',','.')
//   change params to         ^   ^
```

RESULT

```
6.099,99
```

Comment: In what manner? @AndrewHardiman

Comment: But I have added some explanation. If you means [this answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393095/2310830) There is no explanation of why you are suggesting to make whatever changes you made to the code @AndrewHardiman